# Uninstalling Python3.7 in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, installation

I have installed Python3.7 manually following this link: https://websiteforstudents.com/installing-the-latest-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/.

I already have default Python3.4 in the Ubuntu. I am unable to install Python 3.7.
Please help me on doing this.

Answer (score 4):

To be certain, list the available `python` versions using

```py
python3 --version
```

With this confirmation, you can uninstall the version you do not want (3.7) by running:

```py
sudo apt remove python3.7 #this removes only the python package
```

To remove the python package and any other dependant package which are no longer needed, run:

```py
sudo apt autoremove python
```

If you also want to delete configuration and/or data files of python from Ubuntu, run:

```py
sudo apt purge python
```

To remove all related `python3.7` configuration, data files, and dependencies, run:

```py
sudo apt autoremove --purge python
```

Comment: sudo apt remove 3.7 is showing it is not installed, so can't uninstall

Comment: What do you get when you run `python3 --version`?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. For python3 --version, it is showing 3.7.4, but no apt command working on it. I actually want where the folder is, if we install according to given link?